# InfluxDB in Docker not able to move data volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

i have InfluxDB running in docker and mounted a persistent volume for /var/lib/influxdb.

Every thing was fine and data has been stored.

Then I changed the path for my external volume.

So I stopped the container, created the new path, moved the content of the old volume to the new path, changed docker-compose url and restarted the container.

But all my data was gone, InfluxDB looked quite new.

After some trials I restored the original situation but still my data is lost.

Is there any trick with InfluxDB? Because normally this should work with out any problem.

Update:

docker-compose before:

```
  influxdb:
image: influxdb
container_name: influxdb
logging:
  options:
    max-size: "10m"
    max-file: "5"
ports:
  - 8086:8086
environment:
  - INFLUXDB_USER=XXX
  - INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=XXX
volumes:
  - /home/XXX/docker-data/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb:z
  - /home/XXX/docker-data/influxdb/.influx_history:/.influx_history
restart: always
```

after:

```
  influxdb:
image: influxdb
container_name: influxdb
logging:
  options:
    max-size: "10m"
    max-file: "5"
ports:
  - 8086:8086
environment:
  - INFLUXDB_USER=XXX
  - INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=XXX
volumes:
  - /home/XXX/docker-data/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb:z
  - /home/XX/docker-data/influxdb/config:/etc/influxdb:z
  - /home/XX/docker-data/influxdb/.influx_history:/.influx_history
restart: always
```

Comment: please post the docker-compose before and after your modification

Comment: I've updated my original post

Comment: Have you checked the files permissions and owner after moving them ?  This might be an issue makes the data unreadable

Comment: Yes, they worked and InfluxDB created other files

Comment: Do you mean that the problem solved ? or InfluxDB is overriding your data ?

Comment: It just means despite the fact I move the files into the folder InfluxDB is ignoring them and create new files in the same folder

Comment: I've noticed that owner rights are not quite correct:
`drwxrwxr-x 5 1000 1000 4096 Jun 10 08:00 /var/lib/influxdb/`
but inside the directory everything is owned by root: `drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 10 08:00 /var/lib/influxdb/data`

Comment: Moreover the `influxdb` UID should be 999 according to images /etc/passwd: `influxdb:x:999:999::/var/lib/influxdb:/bin/false`